# Why are there so many print functions in C?

Tags: c

What's the difference between `printf`, `fprintf`, `sprintf`, `vprintf`, `vsprintf`, `vfprintf`?

It would also be helpful to know the difference between `scanf`, `sscanf` and `fscanf` and the difference between any more functions like these.

Comment: why don't read the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)? Just look at the prefix and you'll know each function's job. There are even wprintf, fwprintf, wprintf_s, fwprintf_s...

Comment: What books do you read, or what tutorials do you follow? What do they say about it?

Comment: While "read the docs" is not an answer to your question, you will have to specify which parts of the docs are unclear to you, or what in the docs prevents you from seeing the difference. The details are needed to focus your question on what you need explained.

Answer (score 2):

Most of these functions are actually declinations of the first one in each case

- `printf` constructs a formatted string then sends it to *standard output* stream;
- `fprintf` does the same but sends it to any **file** or stream. It allows you to specify an explicit destination stream instead of standard output;
- `sprintf` works the same way as well, but stores the result in a **string**, that is a dedicated buffer in memory, so it can be reused again;

Finaly, `v…` functions act just as the functions above, but accepting "variadic" arguments, which actually consists in directly accepting "va_args" arguments, which enables you to construct your own « printf » function upon existing ones.

Same philosophy applies for `scanf` functions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the documentation with the part you're interested in : [man 3 printf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html)

```
       The functions in the printf() family produce output according to
       a format as described below.  The functions printf() and
       vprintf() write output to stdout, the standard output stream;
       fprintf() and vfprintf() write output to the given output stream;
       sprintf(), snprintf(), vsprintf(), and vsnprintf() write to the
       character string str.

       The function dprintf() is the same as fprintf() except that it
       outputs to a file descriptor, fd, instead of to a stdio(3)
       stream.

       The functions snprintf() and vsnprintf() write at most size bytes
       (including the terminating null byte ('\0')) to str.

       The functions vprintf(), vfprintf(), vdprintf(), vsprintf(),
       vsnprintf() are equivalent to the functions printf(), fprintf(),
       dprintf(), sprintf(), snprintf(), respectively, except that they
       are called with a va_list instead of a variable number of
       arguments.  These functions do not call the va_end macro.
       Because they invoke the va_arg macro, the value of ap is
       undefined after the call.
```

For `scanf` : [man 3 scanf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)

```
       The scanf() family of functions scans input like sscanf(3), but
       read from a FILE.  It is very difficult to use these functions
       correctly, and it is preferable to read entire lines with
       fgets(3) or getline(3) and parse them later with sscanf(3) or
       more specialized functions such as strtol(3).

       The scanf() function reads input from the standard input stream
       stdin and fscanf() reads input from the stream pointer stream.

       The vfscanf() function is analogous to vfprintf(3) and reads
       input from the stream pointer stream using a variable argument
       list of pointers (see stdarg(3).  The vscanf() function is
       analogous to vprintf(3) and reads from the standard input.
```

For `sscanf` : [man 3 sscanf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html)

```
 The sscanf() family of functions scans input according to format
       as described below.  This format may contain conversion
       specifications; the results from such conversions, if any, are
       stored in the locations pointed to by the pointer arguments that
       follow format.  Each pointer argument must be of a type that is
       appropriate for the value returned by the corresponding
       conversion specification.

       If the number of conversion specifications in format exceeds the
       number of pointer arguments, the results are undefined.  If the
       number of pointer arguments exceeds the number of conversion
       specifications, then the excess pointer arguments are evaluated,
       but are otherwise ignored.

       sscanf() These functions read their input from the string pointed
       to by str.

       The vsscanf() function is analogous to vsprintf(3).
```

**tl ; dr**

- printf : Take a format, variables and write to STDOUT
- fprintf : Take a pointer to a file, a format and arguments, and write to the file pointed to
- dprintf : Like fprintf but uses a file descriptor instead of a pointer

All these functions return the number of characters written.

- scanf : Take a format as a parameter, and pointers to the variables to be filled in
- fscanf : Take a pointer to the file in addition to the format and pointers to the variables to be filled in
- sscanf : Similar to the above, but takes a character string as argument, which will be filled in via this function

Functions of the same name beginning with 'v' (for "variadic") have the same behavior as the previous ones, but take a `va_list` instead of arguments.